# Counting combinations of a group of elements with same value

Tags: r, combinations

Sorry about my english, i need some help.

With this dataset:

```
+--------+------------+---------+---------+----------+
| PEOPLE |    DATE    | EVENT_A | EVENT_B | BEVENT_C |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+----------+
| MIKE   | 04/08/2013 |       1 |       1 |        1 |
| PETE   | 10/08/2013 |       1 |       0 |        1 |
| PETE   | 25/08/2013 |       1 |       0 |        1 |
| PETE   | 15/09/2013 |       1 |       0 |        1 |
| MIKE   | 28/09/2013 |       1 |       1 |        1 |
| PETE   | 19/10/2013 |       1 |       1 |        1 |
| MIKE   | 30/10/2013 |       0 |       1 |        1 |
| MIKE   | 09/11/2013 |       1 |       1 |        1 |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Basically i need to count the number of combinations grouped by n events with value of 1. I don't know what approach to take for achieve this in R for example. The output should be something like this:

```
+-------+-------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+
| #MIKE | #PETE | #N EVENTS COMBINATIONS |         |         |        |
+-------+-------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+
|     3 |     1 | COMBINATIONS WITH 2    | EVENT A | EVENT B |        |
|     2 |     4 | COMBINATIONS WITH 2    | EVENT A | EVENT C |        |
|     4 |     1 | COMBINATIONS WITH 2    | EVENT B | EVENT C |        |
|     3 |     2 | COMBINATIONS WITH 3    | EVENT A | EVENT B | EVENT C|
+-------+-------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I need this for every people and for any number of unique events (columns)

Thanks in advance
Vince.

Comment: please include code blocks, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: for you to be helped, you need to atleaste give us the data to work with and the expected results.. not in a jpg format. But in a dataframe.. please check the link given above

Comment: Sorry, i'll try to elaborate and editing with aditional infomation. Thank you

Comment: Please make sure any data you share is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use `dplyr`, piping, and `tidyr` (see more about them [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) and [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/)).

Given your data, I would solve your problem like so:

```
library(dplyr)  # for data manipulation and piping
library(tidyr)  # for data reshaping

# 1. create the data
df <- data_frame(
 people = c("Mike", "Pete", "Pete", "Pete", "Mike", "Pete", "Mike", "Mike"),
 event_a = c(rep(1, 6), 0, 1),
 event_b = c(1, 0, 0, 0, rep(1, 4)),
 event_c = c(rep(1, 8))
)

# create a dummy var for each event-combination
df2 <- df %>% 
 mutate(ab = event_a & event_b,
        ac = event_a & event_c,
        bc = event_b & event_c,
        abc = event_a & event_b & event_c)

# reshape data to the long format using tidyr::gather
df3 <- df2 %>% 
 # we dont need the original events anymore -> deselect them
 select(-contains("event")) %>% 
 # reshape from long to short
 gather("var", "value", -people) %>%
 # filter only the positive matches
 filter(value == T)

df3 %>% 
 # for each combination ...
 group_by(var) %>% 
 # ... count the number of cases
 summarise(n_mike = sum(people == "Mike"),
           n_pete = sum(people == "Pete")) %>%
 # create the text-variable
 mutate(event_combs = sprintf("Combinations with %d", nchar(var))) %>% 
 # reorder to have it your format
 select(n_mike, n_pete, event_combs, var)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   n_mike n_pete         event_combs   var
#>    <int>  <int>               <chr> <chr>
#> 1      3      1 Combinations with 2    ab
#> 2      3      1 Combinations with 3   abc
#> 3      3      4 Combinations with 2    ac
#> 4      4      1 Combinations with 2    bc
```

## Generalization

To generalize this to arbitrary* many events (* max 26 so far as we use `letters`, to extend that is left as an exercise...), we can use the `expand.grid()` to generate all possible event-combinations and then use `apply` to filter the respective combinations.

The code would look like this:

```
df <- data_frame(
 people = c("Mike", "Pete", "Pete", "Pete", "Mike", "Pete", "Mike", "Mike"),
 event_a = c(rep(1, 6), 0, 1),
 event_b = c(1, 0, 0, 0, rep(1, 4)),
 event_c = c(rep(1, 8)),
 event_d = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
)

# take only the events
df_events <- df %>% select(starts_with("event"))
# create all possible event combinations
# also: discard the first rows (all-zeros)
event_combs <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), ncol(df_events)))[-1, ]

# 'loop' over the possible combinations, and find the matches
res_list <- apply(event_combs, 1, function(row) {
 # row now contains which events we choose
 row <- as.logical(row)
 # var now contains the names of the events. i.e., 'a', 'abc', or 'bc'
 var <- paste(letters[1:length(row)][row], collapse = "")

 # combine the data into a data_frame
 data_frame(var = var,
            people = df$people,
            # check if per row all selected events are true
            value = rowSums(df_events[, row]) == sum(row))
})

# bind the results together
df3 <- bind_rows(res_list) %>% filter(value == T)

# same as before...
df3 %>% 
 group_by(var) %>% 
 summarise(n_mike = sum(people == "Mike"),
           n_pete = sum(people == "Pete"))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>      var n_mike n_pete
#>    <chr>  <int>  <int>
#>  1     a      3      4
#>  2    ab      3      1
#>  3   abc      3      1
#>  4  abcd      2      1
#>  5   abd      2      1
#>  6    ac      3      4
#>  7   acd      2      2
#>  8    ad      2      2
#>  9     b      4      1
#> 10    bc      4      1
#> 11   bcd      2      1
#> 12    bd      2      1
#> 13     c      4      4
#> 14    cd      2      2
#> 15     d      2      2
```

Comment: Thank you David, awasome. It would be great if the "mutate" step could work for any number of columns and not creating the combinations by hand. Could it be done?.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much David

Comment: Sorry David. It shows me an error Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
Evaluation error: object 'value' not found. On df3 step.

Comment: Still works on my machine, make sure that you have the latest dplyr version installed (currently at 0.7.2).